# dotnet core getting id from end of url

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I have this method which gets triggered at /api/values/{any number}.

```
public class ValuesController : Controller
{

    [HttpPut("{id}")] 
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(id);
        Program.GetCustomer(id);
    }
}
```

The Console.WriteLine(id) is returning a value of 0 when it should be returning the number at the end of the url. I'm not sure if I'm just misunderstanding how this is meant to work?

Answer (score 0):

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller {    
    [HttpPut("{id:int}")] //Matches PUT api/values/5 
    public IActionResult Put(int id, [FromBody]string value) {
        Console.WriteLine(id.ToString());
        var customer = Program.GetCustomer(id);
        return customer != null ? Ok(customer) : NotFound();
    }
}
```

The above controller and action should match a PUT request to

```
http://<host>/api/values/5
```

where `id` should be mapped to the value `5` in the action and the `value` populated with what was sent in the body of the request.

The route constraint `{id:int}` ensures that the route is matched for valid integers entered in the URL segment.

If the constraint was removed and an invalid integer was entered the value of `id` would be mapped to its default value `0` as the value when parsed would not parse to a valid integer.

Comment: Ah ok so it literally only matches to 5? I thought that was just an example number.

Comment: @Matt `5` is just an example number. It will match any valid integer.